# images arent displaying from db in django 2.2 even if i get my url correct and include static and media root in settings and url

Tags: django, sqlite, django-templates

my image isnt displaying .

I have tried putting all the urls and roots for static and media but it isnt working for 2.2 version.

```
#in settings.py
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),]

    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

#in main urls.py
    + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
#in app urls .py
    if settings.DEBUG:
        urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, 
    document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
        urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, 
    document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: What does URL gives you ? Is it wrong or you're getting a 404 ?

Comment: Im getting the correct url path which is media/images/.. but my image is not displaying.

Comment: you shouldn't set these url patterns inside your app, only in the main urls. And there you're missing the media urls.

Comment: i have tried removing the urls in app and setting it in the main urls but the result remains same

Comment: You're saying your image is not displayed. 
Is it due to a 404 error ? Url not displayed correctly in template ?

Comment: The url in the template is correct but the image isnt displaying

Comment: my image isnt displaying in this url http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/1.png